# Collective term for uncountable nouns for places, like "hospital", "school", "prison", "court", "church"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, terminology

Certain nouns for places, locations or buildings seem to have idiomatic uncountability.

[This blog](https://blog.tjtaylor.net/articles-explained/) lists a couple of those.

> Idiomatic uses:
>
> 1. Home / town: No article precedes ‘home’ unless you add extra information (for example an adjective) or ‘town’ when it refers to your own town.
> 2. Bed / church / court / prison / school / college / university / hospital / work: No article before those nouns when they refer to an action rather than a place.

These are idiosyncratic words referring to places people frequent. Most of them do not require a determiner:

> I go to school (to study).
> I went to church on Sunday (to attend church services).

...or do only when you're doing something that's not an intrisic purpose of the place:

> I went to the school, not to study, but to pick up my kid.
> I went to the local church to take some photos of the interior.

...and then there's *hospital*:

> I went to hospital for my yearly checkup. (British English)
> I went to the hospital for my annual exam. (American English)

What is the descriptor for these select few nouns.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139415/discussion-on-question-by-vun-hugh-vaw-collective-term-for-uncountable-nouns-for).